# When proving the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra with complex analysis, why doese $P(z)\to\infty$ as $z\to\infty$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Theorem: Every non-constant polynomial with complex coefficients has a zero in $\mathbb{C}$.

Proof: Let $P(z)$ be any non-constant polynomial.  Assume by way of contradiction that $P(z)\neq 0$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$.  Then the function $f(z):=1/P(z)$ is an entire function.  Since $P$ is non-constant, $P\rightarrow \infty$ as $z\rightarrow\infty$, so that $f$ is bounded.  By Liouville's Theorem $f$ is constant.  Then $P$ is constant, a contradiction.  Hence $P$ has a zero in $\mathbb{C}$.

I am trying to understand this proof, but I am stuck on "$P\rightarrow\infty$ as $z\rightarrow\infty$."  Could somebody provide further details, please?

Comment: $P(z)=z^n+\ldots $, with leading term $z^n$. Show that this means $P\to \infty$ for $z\to \infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $P(z) = a_nz^n + a_{n-1}z^{n-1} + \dots + a_1 z + a_0$. Then $P(z) = z^n \left( a_n + \frac{a_{n-1}}{z} + \dots + \frac{a_1}{z^{n-1}} + \frac{a_0}{z^n}\right)$, and so if $z\to \infty$, you might notice something happens with the other terms.